# Column height via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-columns

I am using

```
columns: 15em;
```

to automagically format some images on a page. I would like to put filler images in the empty bottoms of the columns, shorter then the longest column. Can I find out what height these images would need to be?

Also sometimes the columns don't format the images optimally. Am I missing something here?

You can play around with my code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ygc6r0as/

Comment: Why not use `background-image`?

Comment: slime: I would like to user specific images as fillers, not just a "grey" or something everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a start. It passes through the images and determines which column the image is currently placed in using simple arithmetic, as well as the total height of each column.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    cols = [],
    colHeights = [], 
    baseOffset = images[0].offsetLeft;

for (var i=0; i < images.length; i++) { 
    var img = images[i];
    var col = Math.round( (img.offsetLeft - baseOffset) / img.width );
    if (!cols[col]) { 
        cols[col] = [];
        colHeights[col] = 0;
    }
    cols[col].push( img );
    var bottom = img.offsetTop + img.offsetHeight;
    if (bottom > colHeights[col]) 
        colHeights[col] = bottom;
}
console.log(cols, colHeights);
```